# CMake: Как добавить qt классы в подпроект?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, cmake

1. Как добавить в `a.cpp` библиотеки `Qt`? (в a.cpp `#include <QDebug.h>` не находит файл)
2. Как избавиться от относительного пути? (в mainwindow.cpp заменить строчку `#include "../a/a.h"` на `#include "a.h"`)
3. Советы и предложения. Я только начинаю изучать CMake.

Проект пустой, который создается по умолчанию (в формате qmake).

**Структура проекта**

```
+ cmakeTest
    - CMakeLists.txt
    + test
        - CMakeLists.txt
        - main.cpp
        - mainwindow.h
        - mainwindow.cpp
        - mainwindow.ui
    + a
        - CMakeLists.txt
        - a.h
        - a.cpp
```

**cmakeTest/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.0)

project(cmakeTest)

add_subdirectory(test)
add_subdirectory(a)
```

**cmakeTest/test/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.0)

project(test)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
# Create code from a list of Qt designer ui files
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

set(test_SRCS
    mainwindow.ui
    mainwindow.cpp
    main.cpp
)

add_executable(helloworld WIN32 ${test_SRCS})

# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5
target_link_libraries(helloworld Qt5::Widgets aLib)
```

**cmakeTest/a/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.0)

set(a_SRCS
    a.cpp
)

add_library(aLib STATIC ${a_SRCS})
```

**cmakeTest/test/mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "../a/a.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    A a;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**cmakeTest/a/a.cpp**

```
#include "a.h"
#include <iostream>
//#include <QDebug.h> // не находит =(

A::A()
{
    std::cout << "class A" << std::endl;
}
```

---

**UDP: Решение**

1. Найти виджеты и добавить директории:

**cmakeTest/a/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.0)

find_package(Qt5Widgets)
include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(a_SRCS
    a.cpp
    a.h
)

add_library(aLib STATIC ${a_SRCS})
```

2. Добавления путей поиска заголовков:

**cmakeTest/test/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.0)

project(test)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
# Create code from a list of Qt designer ui files
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

set(test_SRCS
    mainwindow.ui
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    main.cpp
)

add_executable(helloworld WIN32 ${test_SRCS})

target_include_directories(helloworld PUBLIC ../a)

# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5
target_link_libraries(helloworld Qt5::Widgets aLib)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) вы не можете в cpp файл добавить библиотеку - #include это директива препроцессора и для того, чтобы она верно работала нужно либо указывать полный путь к хидеру (плохой вариант), либо указать компилятору где его искать. В cmake это делается указанием target_include_directories. В случае с qt достаточно указать target_link_libraries с соответствующим модулем.

2) смотрите первый

3) смотрите официальную документацию. Есть ещё методичка на русском: Дубров "система построения проектов cmake"

Comment: спасибо за помощь. у меня получилось использовать QT добавив строчки: `find_package(Qt5Widgets)` и `include_directories(${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})`. Как использовать `target_include_directories` для решения пункта `2`.

Comment: @KtoTo смотрите пункт 3

Comment: отдельное спасибо за книжку, уже заказал