# add_subdirectory добавить папку уровня выше

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, cmake

Продолжение изучения [CMake: Как добавить qt классы в подпроект?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/995084). Теперь необходимо без корневого файла CMakeLists.txt собрать тот же проект.

```
+ root
    - CMakeLists.txt # не используя этот файл!!!
    + test
        - CMakeLists.txt # основа проекта тут!
        - main.cpp
        - mainwindow.h
        - mainwindow.cpp
        - mainwindow.ui
    + a
        - CMakeLists.txt
        - a.h
        - a.cpp
```

Варианты которые попробовал и которые не заработали отмечены `#x`, где `x` - номер попытки. Обе попытки вызывают ошибку.

**root/test/CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15.0)

project(test)

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
# Create code from a list of Qt designer ui files
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

set(test_SRCS
    mainwindow.ui
    mainwindow.cpp
    mainwindow.h
    main.cpp
)

add_executable(helloworld WIN32 ${test_SRCS})

target_include_directories(helloworld PUBLIC ../a)

add_subdirectory(../a) # 1

find_package(          # 2
    aLib               # 2
    PATHS ../a         # 2
    REQUIRED           # 2
    )                  # 2

# Use the Widgets module from Qt 5
target_link_libraries(helloworld Qt5::Widgets aLib)
```

Видимо, такое в cmake не одобряется.

**UDP:**
Если класс `a` является библиотекой(исходники), которая используется несколькими проектами, и для этой библиотеки есть код включения(`a/CMakeLists.txt`), как быть? копировать исходники в каждый используемый объект? Тогда возможно расхождение.

Comment: В cmake нельзя легально добавить как субдиректрию вышестоящую директорию (на то это и называется: субдиректрию)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Если класс `a` является библиотекой(исходники), которая используется несколькими проектами, и для этой библиотеки есть код включения(`a/CMakeLists.txt`), как быть? копировать исходники в каждый используемый объект? Тогда возможно расхождение

Comment: решать подобные проблемы - не задача cmake. Зато с этим прекрасно справляется git. Загуглите субмодули